# Durable clear finish over lettering on natural background

Tags: finishing, paint, surface-preparation

I am making a skittles board with b2 birch plywood.  For those that don't know, this is not a candy server - it is a tabletop game somewhat like a combination of bowling, shuffleboard and top spinning.  A 2' x 4' open top box is divided into a few "rooms" with open doors between them.  Miniature bowling pins are set up in the rooms, and you set a top spinning from one end of the apparatus to knock them over.
[image: People playing skittles]

I am trying to follow the plans here fairly closely: [PDF plan of skittle board](https://www.vintageprojects.com/kids/SkittlesGame.pdf)

Their recommendation for finishing is as follows:

> After   cutting   all   doorways—a   job   you   can speed  by  careful  stacking  of  the  blanks—sand edges  smooth.  A  coat  of  shellac  thinned  50  per-cent  with  alcohol,   followed   with   two   coats   of enamel  makes  a durable  finish.  Brushing is  easier if  you  prefinish  the  parts  before  you  glue  and nail  them  together.The smoother the  finish  on  the  floor,  the longer the  top  will  spin,  so  give  it  extra  care  and  attention.  Sand  carefully  between  each  coat  of  shellac and enamel;  then  apply  a paste  wax  and  buff it  to a hard  finish  before  assembly

What this doesn't address is when to apply the lettering indicating scores for various pins.  Is that the first step?  The last?  (Probably not the last, since the painted lettering would leave a little bit of a textural variation.)

Plus these directions are pretty old -maybe there is a better technique overall.

What methods should I use to get bright red and blue numbers to end up visible on the (very smooth) "floor" of the box?

My question is similar to this one: [Finish for hand painted/lettered wood sign](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/finish-for-hand-painted-lettered-wood-sign)  but I am not particularly concerned about the end result being waterproof, but I do need it to be durable against clattering pins

Comment: My guess, and it is a guess because the instructions aren't clear, is that the surfaces are mainly finished with shellac and wax, with only the numbers done using the enamel. The shellac is therefore being used only as a sealer coat (something that used to be very common and is still done) which is further supported by it being thinned by half rather than being used at full strength.

Comment: I would use a water borne poly as it inparts very little coiour to the wood and by assumption to any numbers.